# Will a store bought cabbage kill my Pieris brassicaes?

Tags: entomology

About 4 days ago I found a large amount of caterpillars (Pieris brassicae) in my radishes, I took them aside for seeing how they grow and I am out of radishes to give them. I bought a cabbage in the supermarket to give them as food but I am concerned it could be GMO anti pests which to my understanding could kill the caterpillars.
I took one of them aside and it is happily eating the cabbage, if this cabbage is designed to resist pests how long would it take for the caterpillar to die since she started eating?

Thank you so much for the info :)

Comment: I wasn't aware GMO cabbage was available at grocery stores. A quick search for GMO cabbage gave some hits for a scorpion venom gene being added to cabbage, but I couldn't find anything suggesting it was being sold for food yet. Do you have more information?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information on the GMO cabbage?

Comment: I am not sure the cabbage has gmo, but I naturally think it might have because usually chains like LIDER (Chilean Walmart) where I bought the cabbage works with massive producers. any ways… the caterpillars are still eating and are not dead yet hehe :)